# C++ assign object value in uninitialized memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing a B-Tree class for databases.

```
  struct Node {
    // invariant: t - 1 <= size <= 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: capacity 2 * t - 1
    K *keys_ = nullptr;
    
    // invariant: t <= size <= 2 * t
    // invariant: size of children_ is size of keys_ + 1
    // invariant: capacity 2 * t
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Node>, 2 * t> children_;

    // number of stored keys
    // invariant: except root, the number of keys is at least t - 1, at most 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: except root, for non-leaf nodes, the number of children is at least t, at most 2 * t
    // invariant: child_0 <= key_0 <= child_1 <= key_1 <= ... <= key_(N - 1) <= child_N
    std::ptrdiff_t N_ = 0; 
    
    Node *parent_ = nullptr;

    Node() : keys_(alloc_.allocate(2 * t - 1)) {
      children_.fill(nullptr);
    }
    ~Node() noexcept {
      alloc_.deallocate(keys_, 2 * t - 1);
    }
    
    Node(const BTreeNodeBase &node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(const BTreeNodeBase &node) = delete;
    Node(BTreeNodeBase &&node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(BTreeNodeBase &&node) = delete;
  };
```

Here, `alloc_` is an allocator of `BTree`. Of course, `value_type` of `alloc_` is `K`. I'm using polymorphic allocators, so that it can allocate or deallocate from memory resources from the main memory or the disk file (which will be my main use case).

`keys_` is not initialized, it is just allocated as raw memory. I don't want to initialize it at constructor of `Node` unless it is really necessary.

To get to the point, is it safe to insert key like `node->keys[i] = K;`? The type restriction of keys is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
concept DiskAllocable = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>
    && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && (sizeof(T) % alignof(T) == 0);
```

Other than these, there are no more restrictions. Is it safe to assign an object of type `T` to uninitialized memory `T*`? Or do I need more restrictions?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<K> keys_;` and `keys_.reserve(2 * t + 1);` if you want to avoid allocations?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I already considered that (it would be ```std::pmr::vector<K>```), but my ```BTree``` should use a single allocator by design. Using ```std::pmr::vector<K>``` for each node would make all nodes have different allocators (with the same type)

Comment: Sorry, I mend `std::pmr::vector<K,  std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<K>> keys_;`.

Comment: Right, but my custom allocator for BTree should be able to deal with allocating/deallocating from possibly gigabytes sized memory mapped disk file. So its size is not zero (to control memory mapped pointer offsets), so only single allocator for ```BTree``` is allowed. Using ```std::pmr::vector``` for each node would make one allocator for each node.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the idea behind having a "resource" and an "allocator". Your memory mapped disk file is the `std::pmr::memory_resource` you use with the allocator. "The polymorphic_allocator::construct member function does uses-allocator construction, so that the elements of a container using a polymorphic_allocator will use that same allocator for their own allocations. For example, a std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::string> will use the same memory_resource for the vector's storage and each string's storage." Same should work for your BTree.

Comment: No, my custom allocator also needs nonzero sized member variable. I'm not using ```std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<K>```. It is actually an allocator for fixed-size objects (in this case, it is always ```sizeof(K) * (2 * t - 1)```), so it uses different mechanism with standard ```malloc```/```free```. The allocator calculates indices of allocated/deallocated chunks, and it is multilpled by ```sizeof(K) * (2 * t - 1)```. Anyway, the allocator is still a stateful object that controls offsets

Comment: Still don't see a problem (apart from there maybe being a miss-design in the allocator). The vector would allocate `sizeof(K) * (2 * t - 1)` chunks if you reserve that much in the constructor. Why isn't your memory resource splitting the memory into `sizeof(K) * (2 * t - 1)` chunks and keeping track of free and allocated indexes?

Comment: You think you understand so much better than me about my custom allocator, its algorithm, and its design purpose so that making allocator stateful is "a miss-design". I already repeated several times, "this allocator needs nonzero sized member variable". A ```std::vector``` stores its allocator as member variable (not its reference), so passing the allocator an argument will make a copy. If I use ```keys_``` as ```std::pmr::vector<K>``` and construct as ```keys_ (alloc_)```  in a constructor of ```Node```, it will copy ```alloc_``` to a member variable of  ```keys_```.

Comment: What I call a miss-design is that your allocator is non-copyable. The idea behind the memory resource and polymorphic allocator was that you could actually have nested container like vector of strings use a common allocator. Yes, every Node and vector would make a copy of the allocator but it's supposed to work with that and store all the data in a single memory resource if so desired. You broke one of the design goals of the memory resource / allocator idea.

Comment: "every Node and vector would make a copy of the allocator but it's supposed to work with that" - No. Who says that? It seems that it is you who is misunderstanding the difference between memory resources and allocators. Using a single memory resource doesn't necessarily mean that you should use a unique (not distinguishable) allocator. You're being stubborn to copy a global allocator object everywhere just because you want to use ```std::pmr::vector``` without any good reason.

Comment: I think not having to deal with allocating, resizing, construction and destruction of all the keys is a good reason. But your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `construct_at` then you don't have any restrictions and `alloc_.allocate<T>(n)` will allocate you a suitably allocated block of memory.